# Blank fields in modal after Ajax success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am successfully calling a controller (Laravel) and returning json data.

How can I map the returned json data to a Modal that opens up when the call is made? The console log prints the response data with all fields. So I have been trying different way on these two lines:

> $('input[name=starts_at]').val(response.starts_at);
>   $('input[name=ends_at]').val(response.ends_at);

I have tried this but returns undefined error.

> $('input[name=starts_at]').val(response[0].starts_at);
>   $('input[name=ends_at]').val(response[0].ends_at);

The Ajax call is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.editApptModal-button').click(function() {
            var appointmentID = $(this).attr('data-appointmentID'); 
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'get',
                    url: '/ajax',
                    data: {id:appointmentID},
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);                      
                        $('input[name=starts_at]').val(response.starts_at);
                        $('input[name=ends_at]').val(response.ends_at);
                        $('#editApptModal').modal('show');
                    },
                    error: function(response){
                        alert('Could not displaying data'+response);
                    }           
                });
            });
        });
```

Console log data

```
 Object {data: Object}
   data:Object 
    created_at: "2017-06-23 18:35:54"
    ends_at: "2017-06-26 15:00"
    id: 87
    starts_at: "2017-06-26 14:00"
    type: "test"
    updated_at: "2017-07-01 16:52:10"
```

Comment: what this line prints `console.log(response);` ?

Comment: I have edited to add Console data.

Comment: looks like you should do `$('input[name=starts_at]').val(response.data.starts_at);`

Comment: magic. Can you post as an answer so I can up vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your console.log print - it's looks like you should change

`$('input[name=starts_at]').val(response.starts_at);`

to

`$('input[name=starts_at]').val(response.data.starts_at);`